# Cache flush on CyclicBarrier or CountDownLatch like when using synchronized keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-cache

Is there some way how to ensure that java flushes the cache of writes that have been done before the CyclicBarrier or CountDownLatch allows us to continue (as the synchronized keyword does) without using the synchronized keyword?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is already guaranteed by the API.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to calling await() *happen-before* actions that are part of the barrier action, which in turn *happen-before* actions following a successful return from the corresponding await() in other threads.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a read by another thread only if the write operation *happens-before* the read operation.  ... Actions prior to calling CyclicBarrier.await *happen-before* actions performed by the barrier action, and actions performed by the barrier action *happen-before* actions subsequent to a successful return from the corresponding await in other threads.

---

This means

```
thread 1                  thread 2

write x1;                 write x2
barrier.await();          barrier.await();
read x2                   read x1
```

no additional synchronization is needed; `read x2` will see the result of `write x2`

Comment: yes, this guarantees the operation order, but I saw no text mentioning the flush of cache values into memory (so that waiting threads would surely see the results of each other) - my point is if the volatile keyword is required to assure that written value will be shared across all waiting threads that just went trough the barrier

Comment: the *happen-before* is a technical term here; if `write x2` *happen-before* `read x2`, the read will see the effect of the write. you can think of this as 'cache flushing'; though java memory model no longer uses cache/flush concepts.