# How to provoke a concurrent publishing error in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've been trying to provoke a publishing error in some multi-threaded Java code.

The sample below seems like it should do the trick, but so far it runs as expected. Admittedly, I'm running this on an MacBook Pro (OSX 10.7.4 with 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7) with only two cores (and hyper-threading).  So only 4 threads can even run at once.

Any ideas how better to provoke a publishing failure?

```
package demo;

import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class UnsafePublicationTest {
private static final String FIRST_VAL = "FAIL";
private static final String SECOND_VAL = "GOOD";

public void test() throws Exception {
    UnsafePublisher unsafe = new UnsafePublisher();
    unsafe.setValue(FIRST_VAL);
    CyclicBarrier gate = launchThreads(10, unsafe);
    gate.await();  // Start all threads at once
    gate.await();  // Each thread reads the first value

    // Should cause errors since update is not published
    unsafe.setValue(SECOND_VAL);
    gate.await();  // Each thread tries for the second value
    gate.await();  // Wait for the readers finish
}

private CyclicBarrier launchThreads(int count, UnsafePublisher unsafe) {
    CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(count + 1);
    for (int id = 0; id < count; id++) {
        ValueReader rdr = new ValueReader(id, gate, unsafe);
        rdr.start();
    }
    return gate;
}

private static class UnsafePublisher {
    private String fValue;

    public UnsafePublisher() { /* no synthetic ctor */ }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.fValue = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return fValue;
    }
}

private static class ValueReader extends Thread {
    private final int fId;
    private final CyclicBarrier fGate;
    private final UnsafePublisher fTest;

    public ValueReader(int id, CyclicBarrier gate, UnsafePublisher test) {
        fId = id;
        fGate = gate;
        fTest = test;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            fGate.await();
            int noOp = this.hashCode();
            // Try to get the thread to cache the value.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i ++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                    String first = fTest.getValue();
                    noOp = noOp ^ first.hashCode();
                    if (!FIRST_VAL.equals(first))
                        System.out.println("Thread " + fId + " read " + first);
                }
            }
            fGate.await();

            // Between these awaits, the value is changed.

            fGate.await();
            String second = fTest.getValue();
            if (!SECOND_VAL.equals(second))
                System.out.println("Thread " + fId + " read " + second);
            System.out.println("Thread " + fId + " hash " + noOp);
            fGate.await();

        } catch (Exception err) { /* ignore */ }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    UnsafePublicationTest test = new UnsafePublicationTest();
    test.test();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to debug :) I am still trying to understand what you want to achieve, but what you are seeing, to me, is normal and expected (if you dig into it and understand the code). Here is what happens:

- CyclicBarrier is set to 11.

  Suppose that Main Thread starts 10 other Threads and they all start executing their run method.
  But they immediately block. Now the order in which Main Thread and these 10 Threads start up  is not important here. And *it is not important* because in Main Thread you call gate.await() - the second time, thus allowing each thread to execute the for loop.After they are done with the for loop, they call gate.await() - second time, thus lifting the barrier again.

  - Now comes the part that confuses me the most. You make the **third call** to gate.await() in the run method, thus they all block, because the barrier was "lifted" in the previous step. Now the order here is again not important, you could say that Main Thread is first called, setting the value of "fValue" to "GOOD", then the 10 threads wait for the barrier. This is NOT IMPORTANT. What is importnat, is the fact that this statement:

Code (let's call it sample1):

```
String second = test.getValue();
if (!SECOND_VAL.equals(second)){
     System.out.println("Thread " + i + " read " + second); 
}
```

that is inside the run method, will 100% be executed only after this call in main:

```
 unsafe.setValue(SECOND_VAL); // call it sample2
```

I think that the problem is somewhere here (the devil is always in the details :) ).

And *if you agree that sample2 is 100% executed before sample1*, then what are the odds of this code?

```
 if (!SECOND_VAL.equals(second)){
      System.out.println("Thread " + i + " read " + second);
 }
```

Well, to me, NONE.

Thus my question, what are you trying to prove? May be we can think of a better/simpler example? If you still want to stick to this one, then you will have to probably explain more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The point of the test is that the "sample2" code changes the value held in unsafe without properly publishing it (no lock on any object).  If any of the other ten threads had cached the value, it should report spurious value in "sample3".

Comment: @nyc10003 you are using a CyclicBarrier - it guarantees to update the object properly. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493140/cache-flush-on-cyclicbarrier-or-countdownlatch-like-when-using-synchronized-keyw